# KENDO GRID] How to create a column with a FOR statement

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

The model has variables from SUM_01 to SUM_31.

I did not want the code to be long, so I tried to write with the FOR statement as follows. But I get an error saying that I gave STRING instead of model type.

```
  for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
                {
                    string col = "o => o.SUM_0" + i;
                    string title = i + "DAY";
                    columns.Bound(col)
                         .Title(title)
                         .Width(85)
                         .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" })
                         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" });
                }
```

Is there a way? oh, the grid using ZbdModels

```
 @( Html.Kendo().Grid<TEST.Models.ZbdModels>()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify the column definition like this: `col = "o => o.SUM_0" + i`. First of all, Kendo cannot interpret it. Also, you would end up with column names like `SUM_023`. Something like `col = "SUM_" + i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')` should work.